# Rename multiple files using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using these two codes:

1. Get_Files_Information: To pull up the file names from the folder for renaming

```
Option Explicit

Sub Get_Files_Information()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim fo As Folder
Dim f As File

Set fo = fso.GetFolder(sh.Range("H1").Value)

Dim last_raw As Integer

For Each f In fo.Files
     last_raw = sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
     sh.Range("A" & last_raw).Value = f.Name
Next

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

2. Rename_Files: This code is to rename the file

```
Sub Rename_Files()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim fo As Folder
Dim f As File

Dim new_name As String

Set fo = fso.GetFolder(sh.Range("H1").Value)

For Each f In fo.Files
    new_name = Application.VLookup(f.Name, sh.Range("A:B"), 2, 0)
    f.Name = new_name
Next

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

When the Get_Files_Information is fetching the file name the result is coming with file extension. I want to exclude the file extension from the file name so that the renaming will not get stuck due to extension of the file.

Also when executing the rename code I get

> Type Mismatch Runtime error 13.

on `new_name = Application.VLookup(f.Name, sh.Range("A:B"), 2, 0)`

Excel macro file for reference.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Zivo3aIn-Id9XtgQu-qpOstL_j7eacjv

Comment: declare new_name as string... have you tried looking at new_name with `Debug.Print`to see, what your Lookup returns?

Comment: Runtime error-13

Comment: Code is running for me. I'd recommend to add some example data to the post as like me most people will not download a file from a google drive.

Comment: column A will have the old file name and the column 2 will have new file name i am getting this error while executing the code https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEnuN.png

Comment: It would be great if you could add this information to the post, mark the line where the error occurs and add the data in the variables and cells.

Comment: udpated please check

Comment: It would help if you added also the values of `f.Name`, `sh.Range("A:B")` and `Application.VLookup(f.Name, sh.Range("A:B"), 2, 0)`. You will find that in the local watch window resp. by adding it to the watch window

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code. It will check if `Application.VLookup(f.Name, sh.Range("A:B"), 2, 0)` returns an error (probably caused by a formula which returned an error like #VALUE)

```
Sub Rename_Files()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim fo As Folder
    Dim f As File

    Dim new_name As String

    Set fo = fso.GetFolder(sh.Range("H1").Value)

    For Each f In fo.Files
        Dim vRes As Variant
        vRes = Application.VLookup(f.Name, sh.Range("A:B"), 2, 0)
        If IsError(vRes) Then
            MsgBox "Cannot rename " & f.Name & " - " & CStr(vRes)
        Else
            new_name = vRes
            f.Name = new_name
        End If
    Next

    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

This code will also give you a hint what went wrong as it gives you the [cell error value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/Concepts/Cells-and-Ranges/cell-error-values). For an extended discussion on vlookup I recommend to have a look at this [article](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-vlookup/#A_Quick_Guide_to_the_VBA_VLookup)